# Facebook Game Requests - Object not owned by the app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook Game Requests to my Android App.

`GameRequestContent.Builder()` needs to have `.setObjectId()` called, to use `ActionType.SEND` or `ActionType.ASKFOR`. Where do I get this object?

When I try to create object using [Object Manager](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser) or [Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api/) I get this error in the Facebook dialog:

> Object type 'Game' for ID 'xxxxxxxxxx' is not owned by this app.

Even though I always provide App Access Token in the creation process.

I even tried to set tag fb:app_id of the object to id of my app, but that information wasn't saved without any error messages.

I can't seem to find anyone adressing this topic anywhere in this manner, I mainly don't even understand why Object Id is required in a first place, so perhaps I confused more different topics from Facebook api (its terminology can get very confusing).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There’s app-owned and user-owned objects – are you sure you created the right type?

Comment: How do I choose the type when creating them?

Comment: That’s explained in the documentation you already linked to.

Comment: It seems like I created app object, I use app access token and app/objects/ node. It doesn't appear in object browser even if it was successfully created though.

Comment: It is only shown when I put Id into the filter bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am having the same issue.

I just changed my app to live instead of keeping it in debug mode and now it is suddenly working.

I was having the same exact issues you outlined and this worked for me.

I also realized that I changed the object type from `game` to `product`. Even with it set to published/live a game object does not work but a product object works.

Also, upon more research https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph shows object types. There is a `game.achievement`but not a `game`.

There is a `product` object with a description

`This object type represents a product. This includes both virtual and physical products, but it typically represents items that are available in an online store.`

Even though the API and graph explorer gives us an ID for the game object it seems like it isn't the proper object to use.

```
{
  "created_time": "2016-12-13T19:15:59+0000",
  "title": "Shots",
  "type": "product",
  "data": {
    "is_product_shareable": true
  },
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

is the response I get when I do a get on `/v2.8/object ID`

Comment: Yeah, that was it! Thank you, in the end i found out by myself, but forgot about this question, because it was after a longer time.

Comment: Yea I was going to just comment but didn't have enough rep. I am glad you figured it out :) This is good to have here answered for anyone else having trouble :)